# Ajax form $_POST blank return data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
var name = jQuery('[data-field="name"]').val();
var email = jQuery('[data-field="email"]').val();
var inumber = jQuery('[data-field="inumber"]').val();
var rnumber = jQuery('[data-field="rnumber"]').val();
var date = jQuery('[data-field="date"]').val();
var amount = jQuery('[data-field="amount"]').val();
var feedback = jQuery('[data-field="name"]').val();

var file_attach = new FormData(jQuery('input[name^="media"]'));     
jQuery.each(jQuery('input[name^="media"]')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    file_attach.append(i, file);
});
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: { func: "sendMail", name,email,inumber,rnumber,date,amount,feedback,file_attach},
    url: 'billing-information-mailer.php',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

I'm trying to pass form info and attachment to a php file to send an email, initially I just went with `$.post` however I need to set processData to false so I shifted to `$.ajax`, currently my PHP file is sending an empty return. the only code in my php file is `print_r($_POST);`

EDIT:

```
<input type="file" name="media" data-field="billing" id="vdnupload" name="vdnupload" placeholder="Proof of Payment">
```

Comment: try stringifying the json data

Comment: data is invalid you send

Comment: try individually display `jQuery('selector').val()` make sure none of them are `undefined` also check your console if it doesn't have any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of the object you're providing to the `data` property is incorrect as each item needs a key.

However a more pressing problem is that to upload a file you need to put all the data (file and input values) in to the `FormData` object and send that alone. Try this:

```
var formData = new FormData();     
$.each($('input[name^="media"]')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    formData.append(i, file);
});
formData.append('name', $('[data-field="name"]').val());
formData.append('email', $('[data-field="email"]').val());
formData.append('inumber', $('[data-field="rnumber"]').val());
formData.append('rnumber', $('[data-field="rnumber"]').val());
formData.append('date', $('[data-field="date"]').val());
formData.append('amount', $('[data-field="amount"]').val());
formData.append('feedback', $('[data-field="name"]').val());

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    url: 'billing-information-mailer.php',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

You could make this much, much simpler if you place a `form` element around all the inputs you want to include in the request. That way you can just provide a reference of that form to the `FormData` constructor and all values will be populated for you:

```
var formData = new FormData($('#myForm')[0]);
```

Comment: I tried the last option thanks! However the file doesn't pass through to the php file.

Comment: Ok, to help you with that we need to see your HTML and the PHP you're using to access the file in the request. Could you please edit your question to include those.

Comment: Edited the above post, for the php I haven't started handling the uploaded file  yet, I'm assuming I'll be just accessing $_FILE

Comment: That's right. You can refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980733/jquery-ajax-file-upload-php) for details on how to do that

Comment: Thanks man, last question though, Do I really need to store the file before sending? Is there a way to like pass the file to the php and directly send no upload,  rather than pass, upload send then delete.

Comment: No I'm afraid not. The file has to be uploaded to the server first.